# at what point does appreciation of the nude, often male, statue become desire

Tags: word-usage, word-order

*Robertson poses the question **at what point does appreciation** of the nude, often male, statue become desire for the living human body: "appreciation of sculpture can let men express covertly the homosexual desire that is officially prohibited. Does art sublimate desire, or release it?"*

Source: https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.cz/&httpsredir=1&article=2305&context=clcweb

Do you think that the auxiliary verb "does" is used properly before "appreciation"? I would await this word order: Robertson poses the question at what point appreciation of the nude, often male, statue becomes desire…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample sentence:

> Robertson poses the question at what point does appreciation of the
>   nude, often male, statue become desire for the living human body:etc.

Question: Do you think that the auxiliary verb "does" is used properly before "appreciation"?

**does is not an auxiliary verb in the sample sentence. It is an interrogative form of the verb do**.

**Better punctuation would be:**

> Robertson poses the question:  **At what point does appreciation of
>   the nude**, often male, statue become desire for the living human body
>   when he writes "quote?"?

**Does** is the main verb and **it is an interrogative of the verb do**.

Better writing as a single sentence would be:

> Robertson poses the question about **the point at which** appreciation of
>   the nude, often male, statue become desire for the living human body
>   when he writes "quote?"?

**At what point does a sentence need fixing?**

Answer (score 1):

'Does' is used correctly. You can paraphrase Robertson's question (1) using the auxiliary verb 'does' and the base form of the verb (become) or (2) you can eliminate 'does' and use the third person singular 'becomes'.

I ask this question using these words: at what point does heat become painful?

Someone could later write:

(1) Michael Harvey asks (or 'poses the question') at what point **does** heat **become** painful.

or:

(2) Michael Harvey asks (or 'poses the question') at what point heat **becomes** painful.

Comment: I thought that when using the declarative sentence, the auxiliary verb in the meaning of emphasizing should be placed after the subject.

Comment: Ah, but it's not entirely declarative.